# Create Concatenate Text File Using Windows Powershell (FFmpeg)

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, concatenation

I'm trying to using Windows Powershell to create a file list to be used for concatenation in FFmpeg, basically just list all avi files in a given directory but formatted correctly.

Currently this is what I have:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.avi | Format-Table name -hidetableheaders | Out-File 'concat.txt'
```

Gives me a list, but it isn't formatted correctly. Top line is blank (not sure if that matters) and it's just the file names, example:

```
[BLANK]
video001.avi
video002.avi
video003.avi
video004.avi
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
file 'video001.avi'
file 'video002.avi'
file 'video003.avi'
file 'video004.avi'
```

I know how to do this in CMD but can't figure it out in powershell, this is just a component of my full command but the rest is functioning and irrelevant to the question. Trying to stick to powershell because I'm using files on a NAS and use of a network drive in conjunction with CMD can be tiresome.

Comment: As a tip. Format is mainly only for the cmdline output. Never format something you wanna work with.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to have a list of strings that correspond to your example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.avi -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    "file '$PSItem'"
} | Out-File -FilePath "$pwd\concat.txt"
```

`Format-Table` is intended to format objects for console output.  File output? not so much.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm getting an error: "ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'RemainingScripts'. Cannot convert the 'Out-File' value of type 'System.String' to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock'."

Comment: gci -filter *.avi -recurse | foreach {"file '" + $_.name + "'"} > concat.txt

Comment: @Nimble See the update.  I had a typo in my original answer

Comment: Mind you, I haven't tested, but wouldn't you pipe it to `select -expand name` before the loop?

Comment: @Robert Cotterman no. The `ToString` method of a `FileInfo` object will already reduce to the `Name` property

Comment: Thank you this is working great now! One more quick clarification, what would need to be added to add the path of said files in front of the file name? Example: "File 'C:\Users\[User]\videos\video001.avi'"?

Comment: @Nimble Sure - just do `$($PSItem.FullName)` instead

Comment: Works great thank you. PS after adding this bit to my final command I was getting this error - "Line 1: unknown keyword ' ■f'" - adding "-Encoding ascii" to the end of your solution solved the problem.

Comment: @Nimble ah yes, that's a default encoding issue with `Out-File` and ffmpeg being unable to identify the file encoding